# arrows and text following click and hover

Tags: d3.js, hover, interaction

I'm starting a new project with main purpose to learn some basic `d3.js`. Here's my toy problem: I want to draw an interactive flow-chart with a few rectangles, and when the user hovers / clicks on one, I would like to display dependencies with an arrow pointing to other rectangles in the scene. I would also like to display some text elsewhere, conditional on this user action.

The end-goal is something like this:

[image]

Here's my starting point, inspired by some basic tutorials:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var s = 50;
var w = 200;
var h = 100;

var jsonBoxes = [
  {"name": "Box A", "x_axis": s, "y_axis": s, "width": w, "content": "content of Box A", "depends" : "Box C"},
  {"name": "Box B", "x_axis": w + 2*s, "y_axis": s, "width": w, "content": "content of Box B", "depends" : "Box D"},
  {"name": "Box C", "x_axis": 2*(w + s) + s, "y_axis": s, "width": w, "content": "content of Box C", "depends" : "Box D" },
  {"name": "Box D", "x_axis": s, "y_axis":  2*s +h, "width": w, "content" : "content of Box D" , "depends": "Box F"},
  {"name": "Box E", "x_axis": w + 2*s, "y_axis": 2*s+h, "width": w, "content": "content of Box E", "depends" : "Box F" },
  {"name": "Box F", "x_axis": 2*(w + s) + s, "y_axis": 2*s+h, "width": w, "content": "content of Box F", "depends" : "Box A" }];

var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                                    .attr("width", 800)
                                    .attr("height", 300);

var rectangles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                          .data(jsonBoxes)
                          .enter()
                          .append("rect");

var rectanglesAttributes = rectangles
                       .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width; })
                       .attr("height", 100)
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return "Cornsilk"; });

var p = d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
  .data(jsonBoxes)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(function(d) { return d.name + ": " + d.content; });
```

Could someone illustrate (/ point me to) the general procedure to deal with on-hover or on-click and generate content (arrows, text) based on this?

PS: I'm quite comfortable with R to pre-process the data in a more suitable format. I've used yaml as input format, and it seems easy enough to produce json from that as needed. The d3 mapping and interactivity is where I'm a total newbie.

Answer (score 1):

First: on an `<svg>`, you have `<text>` instead of `<p>`, and frustratingly, it won't wrap itself. To wrap text, check out [Mike Bostock's Block](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321).

The general on-click functionality takes this form:

```
selection.on('click', function (data, index) {
    stuff();
})
```

And hovering uses `mouseover` and `mouseout` in the place of `click`. For the subject, it seems like `click` would be a wise choice to show the arrows and `mouseover` for the 'elsewhere text'. In your case, it might look something like this:

```
rectangles.on('click', function (d, i) { //1
    d3.select('svg').append('path').attr('d', pathString); //2
    d3.selectAll('rect').filter(function (k, j) {
        return k.name == d.depends; //3
    }).each(function () {
        d3.select(this).on('click')(); //4
    });
}).on('mouseover', function (d, i) { //5
    d3.select('text#moreinfo').text(d.extraInfo);
});
```

The arrows will need to be `path` elements, and they won't have heads unless you add `polygon` elements to each head.

1. Attach a click event to each rectangle.
2. Append to the `svg` a `path` element (it's a line).
3. Find the prerequisite course's `rect` from it's name.
4. Call the click event for each of these (or singular) prerequisite rectangle(s). Note that since each click event is set up this way, this is actually a recursive call which will draw arrows for each prerequisite down the chain.
5. Attach a mouse hover handler that will change the text of the 'elsewhere text' `text` element, provided that you make it previously.

In order to make the arrows cool and curvy, as in the image, you will need to calculate the path's control points. [Here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/svg-curves/cubic-curve.html) is a cool graphic to explain how paths with Cubic Bézier Curves work. You should be able to calculate the control points with some basic geometry.

I recommend getting really familiar with [`svg`](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_intro.asp) first.

Comment: thanks. I saw the block on text wrapping but it's quite a complicated example since it's part of a bar chart. I'm hoping to find something simpler with just a `div` or something further down the page (separate from the svg, maybe). Regarding arrows and Bezier curves, I would have thought d3 could make nice-looking paths for me, based on examples I've seen (collapsible trees etc.). That being said, since my layout is static, I could simply draw the arrows myself in inkscape and have d3 only change their colour when clicking/hovering.

Comment: It seems like a cool idea and I'd definitely try to do it dynamically if you're up to it. I'm frankly not very familiar with [trees](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#treemap) (and I don't know how well they fit your situation), but you could do something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033), but make the 'node's rectangles and put the `text` on top of it.

Comment: Also for the `div` idea, you can use `d3` as a `DOM` manipulator just like jQuery with statements like: `d3.select('body').append('div').text('foo');` That will certainly make wrapping much easier;